# How to install an individual package in ROS hydro

Tags: ros, source, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install the hector_slam package in ROS. I downloaded the file from the URL, but I don't know where to put it and how to install the package. Instead of having package.xml in the root folder, it has a stack.xml. I don't know the difference and "rosmake" doesn't work here. If I put the files under the /src folder in my catkin workspace, when I run "catkin_make" it doesn't make the files in this package. I found a few methods online for the earlier versions of ROS, one of them is using "rosws", but it gave a lot of errors and I don't really know what to do when specifying a target workspace. It's my first time installing a package from source, could anyone kindly help me? If possible, I wish to know the general way to install packages in ROS.

Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115261/how-to-install-an-individual-package-in-ros-hydro/) by [CathIAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/10501/cathias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below is one of multiple options. This is assuming you have a default hydro setup running, with "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" in your .bashrc file. It will also use the catkin version of hector_slam from source as it appears you want to use catkin (?). If you don´t absolutely require installation from source "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-slam" should also work.

Create a folder somewhere:

```
mkdir hector_slam_test
```

Enter folder, init workspace:

```
cd hector_slam_test
wstool init
```

Copy the following lines to a file named "hector_slam_catkin.rosinstall":

```
- git:
    uri: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git
    local-name: src/hector_slam
    version: catkin
```

/edit: It appears the link gets screwed up by ROS Answers. You can see the correct formatting here: http://answers.ros.org/answers/115386/revisions/

Merge the contents of this rosinstall file into your workspace:

```
wstool merge hector_slam_catkin.rosinstall
```

Update workspace (this updates/pulls all repos belonging to the workspace):

```
wstool update
```

Build contents of workspace:

```
catkin_make
```

Source the setup file in the workspace´s devel folder:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

You should now be able to use hector_slam as expected. For example

```
 roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
```

should start without errors.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CathIAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/10501/cathias/) on 2014-01-08**:
Yes. In fact I used sudo apt-get ros-hydro-hector-slam, and it also worked. To install from source and in a customized workspace, your method is better.

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-10-11**:
When I run: wstool merge hector_slam_catkin.rosinstall

There is an error: ERROR in config: Yaml for each element must be in YAML dict form

Kindly help me to resolve!

mudassar